# ExecuteSqlCommand with Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, lambda, .net-4.5

We are using repository pattern with unit of work pattern to interact with database.
I have the below method to execute stored procedure:

```
/*** Execute stored procedure ***/
public virtual void ExecuteProcedure(String procedureCommand, params SqlParameter[] sqlParams)
{
    Ctxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(procedureCommand, sqlParams);
}
```

However, my manager told me to implement this using lambda expressions.
Can somebody please shed some thoughts how to rewrite this using lambda, and also how to consume this from client??

Comment: Why on earth has he requested that?

Comment: may be becase he wrote other method using lamda, for ex:public virtual T Find(IQueryAggregator<T> qry, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
  {
   return Filter(qry, includes).FirstOrDefault();
  }

Comment: Does EF not allow you to just map stored procedure calls onto the data context? Surely it supports that by now...

Comment: I am not sure what you are talking about? can u please explain

Comment: @Marc-Gravell, yes, EF allows you to map procedure calls to the data context. The only limitation to this technique is that it requires the mapping to be performed during compile-time. (Depending on the developer's perspective, this limitation can also be seen as a blessing.) Using a lambda might allow binding and execution to occur at runtime. Binding and executing database objects at runtime can be seen as great or horrible, depending on the developer and technical requirements.